# Threads reading the same line from one file

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, line, python-multithreading

I'm trying to use threads with python, I'm pretty new to threads. I wanted the threads to read random lines from the same file but all the threads read the same line. So the file I'm trying to read has all the lines in email:pass:another_line format. I expected to read different lines from the same file with multiple threads but its reading the same line with multiple threads.
So for example 1 thread will return line1, second thread will return line2 but its random lines.

```
import random
import threading

def email_pass_token():
    global email, pass2, token

    file = open("testing/pokens.csv").read().splitlines()
    acc_str = random.choice(file)

    num_lines = sum(1 for _ in file)
    print(num_lines)

    email = ":".join(acc_str.split(":", 1)[:1])

    pass2 = ":".join(acc_str.split(":", 2)[:2][1:])

    token = ":".join(acc_str.split(":", 3)[:3][2:])
email_pass_token()

def gen_acc():
    print(email, pass2, token)

threads = []
num_thread = input("Threads: ")
num_thread = int(num_thread)
for i in range(num_thread):
    t = threading.Thread(target=gen_acc)
    threads.append(t)
    t.start()
```

File Sample:

```
tqqe435ihwbta@oncemail.co.kr:#354946345e696$e30*417:another_line1
tkbzw543vwxzn@oncemail.co.kr:2e5548c543709!8@305-8(:another_line2
jcgeau43yphr@oncemail.co.kr:41c!954=7543cc^1#48fd_$*b5:another_line3
bqajs543qlqys@oncemail.co.kr:1f@e54d78^feb54355&6$50:another_line4
tqqeihw54bta@oncemail.co.kr:#3946345e696$e30*417:another_line5
tkbzwvwx543zn@oncemail.co.kr:2e58c5437709!8@305-8(:another_line6
jcgeauy453phr@oncemail.co.kr:41c!9=7543cc^1#48fd_$*b5:another_line7
bqajsqlq54ys@oncemail.co.kr:1f@ed78^feb53455&6$50:another_line8
```

Comment: You need to use a different seed for each thread.

Comment: The code you've presented is not runnable. Show a sample of the tokens.csv and I'll construct an answer for you

Comment: The code as shown does not do what you describe: the threads *don't* read from the file, they all read the same global variable.

Comment: @DarkKnight https://prnt.sc/20xkt91, i belive it can also be a .txt file, doesn't have to be a .csv file

Comment: Please add the file sample into the question as text

Comment: Ditto what MisterMiyagi said: Your `file` variable is not a file. It refers to a list of strings. The only thread in your program that ever reads a file is the main thread, when it calls `email_pass_token()`. The `open(...)` call opens the file for reading, `read()` reads the entire file into one potentially humongous string,\* and then `splitlines()` _parses_ the string into a list of shorter strings (one for each line.)

Comment: \* [Documentation for the `read()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) says, "it’s _your_ problem if the file is twice as large as your machine’s memory."

Answer (score 0):

You are not running the function for selecting line in the threads. What you are doing is you are running `gen_acc` in the threads which only prints the three variables `email`, `pass2` and `token`. Your code for selecting lines resides `email_pass_token` which is called only once.

Comment: And how would I change my code to selecting different lines?

Comment: Instead of `gen_acc` just use `email_pass_token` in `threading.Thread`. BTW, you must know there will a race condition in your code because multiple threads are modifying the same global variables. Also you have to do the printing inside `email_pass_token`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you could do it. Note that this will **not** work if the *password* contains a colon. Also, I've hard-coded the number of threads but you get the idea.

```
import random
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

FILENAME = 'testing/pokens.csv'
NTHREADS = 5

def myfunc():
    with open(FILENAME) as infile:
        lines = infile.readlines()
        line = random.choice(lines).strip()
        tokens = line.split(':')
        return ' '.join(tokens)

def main():
    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        futures = []
        printable = set()
        for _ in range(NTHREADS):
            future = executor.submit(myfunc)
            futures.append(future)
        for future in futures:
            printable.add(future.result())
        for p in printable:
            print(p)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you that worked, but what about race condition? How would I go if I wanted to eliminate all threads that are duplicates? For example, 1 thread prints line1, second thread prints line2, third thread prints line1 again. How would I get rid of thread3?

Comment: There's no race condition here. If you want to avoid duplication in the way you describe then you should change the threaded function (*myfunc*) to return values which you examine in your *main* function to see if you want to print them

Comment: I've edited the answer to show how you *could* avoid duplicate output